# List of all tags used on Stack Overflow

Tags: stackexchange-api

I am building a website, which categorizes IT problems. How can I get the content of all tags used on Stack Overflow?

I need to use the same tagging feature with the same content, but separately.

How can I extract the content of all tags? (It should be a couple of thousand.)

Comment: This should be on meta.stackoverflow.com, and use the data explorer, [like this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/380388). Also, there are over 40 thousand...

Comment: On 2022-11-04, an answer was awarded the [Lifeboat badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8842/lifeboat) here on Stack Overflow...

Comment: Examples of similar questions on meta: *[SO Dataset query to retrieve questions, related answers and comments with a specific question tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378872/)*, *[How to get tags of questions answered by a user in Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378815/)*, and *[Query for getting top users on a specific tag by country sorted by tag score (Stack Overflow)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383074/)*

Comment: But there must also be a meta question about where such questions belong...

Answer (score 25):

You can utilize the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for gathering this type of information.

The [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/381621) below will pull all tags, their excerpts and their wiki content:

```
select 
  t.tagName,
  e.body as 'Excerpt',
  w.body as 'WikiBody'
from tags t
left join Posts e
  on t.ExcerptPostId = e.Id
left join Posts w
  on t.WikiPostId = w.Id
order by t.tagName
```

---

At the time of this post, this returns 42,553 rows.

Note that not all tags have excerpts or wiki content.

Comment: Andy do you have any idea how can i get relationship table of similar tags like if you add tag "php" it shows "php5", "php4" tags as similar tags.

Answer (score 5):

I developed upon [andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335492/list-of-all-tags-used-on-stack-overflow/33392852#33392852) and gathered up each tag's synonyms as well:

```
select e.id,
  count(t.tagName),
  string_agg(TagSynonyms.SourceTagName, ',') as synonyms,
  t.tagName,
  e.body as 'Excerpt',
  w.body as 'WikiBody'
from tags t
left join Posts e
  on t.ExcerptPostId = e.Id
left join Posts w
  on t.WikiPostId = w.Id
left join TagSynonyms 
  on TagSynonyms.TargetTagName = t.tagName
group by t.tagName, e.body, w.body, e.id
order by  count(t.tagName) desc
```

The link is [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1404435/tags-and-their-synonyms).